# Firefox and IE6 issue with document.ready()

Tags: javascript, firefox, internet-explorer-6, google-chrome, document-ready

I have created an html page with a Tabber tab functionality.

- Each tab has its own table that loads when the tab is clicked and only loads once on the initial tab click to stop the tables loading more than once.
- Each tab table exists in its own .jsp html file and is loaded through javascript using the `$("#tab1").load('tabqtable.jsp');` call.

I currently have a `document.ready()` within the individual tab html files to run when each tab loads. The scripts run and work perfectly in Chrome, but the `document.ready()` functions don't run in Firefox and IE6.

I can put an `alert();` outside of the document.ready() function and it works, so I know the script tag is being run. I also tried moving all the javascript to the return function call in the `.load()` function so the javascript will run when the `.load()` runs successfully from the m/ain html page, but still ended up with the same result.

I am at a loss and would really appreciate some help on this issue if I could get it. The tables load perfectly, I just don't get any of the functionality I need in order to interact with the table. It's not the scripts I am running either, because they all work with the main html page. Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Can you post some sample code?

Answer (score 2):

well it looks like you are already using a framework like jquery...use $(document).ready (assuming that's jquery you are using...) the point of frameworks like jquery is that it (in principle) should be crossbrowser compatible.